# Умножение чисел

Tags: javascript

Почему при умножении числа 341 на 0.0000001 я получаю 0.000034099999999999995. Если взять число на разряд меньше (0.000001) вывод будет чистым. Почему так происходит и как этого избежать ?

Comment: `Почему так происходит и как этого избежать ?` -- потому что [IEEE754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55280847/floating-point-number-in-javascript-ieee-754). Избежать нельзя, но можно через другой путь получить результат, можно использовать соответствующие библиотеки (допустим [`bigfloat`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bigfloat)).

Comment: [Не точные вычисления](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#netochnye-vychisleniya) - тут описано, почему так происходит и как с этим можно бороться

Comment: @ΝNL993 думаю, для вычислений лучше использовать https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js, хотя бы по критерию количества загрузок =)